# API fetching with xstate in React

Tags: reactjs, xstate, xstate-react

I am working on a React application which calls a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request and then waits for a response which it then goes through conditions where depending on the condition, a component renders on the page.

How can I implement this with xstate to handle the various conditions?

I made my machine like this:

```
import { createMachine, assign } from 'xstate'

const fetchData = async (context, event) => {
  const { token } = event.params;
  try {
    const res = await fetch(api) // Fetching API here
enter code here
     // Here are some conditions that I am going to use to render data
enter code here
  } catch (error) {
    return { type: 'error', renderType: 'error' }
  }
}


const interviewMachine = createMachine(
  {
    id: 'myMachine',
    initial: 'idle',
    context: {
     // Some values for rendering component based on it
    },

    states: {
      idle: {
        on: {
          FETCH: {
            target: 'loading',
            actions: 'fetchData'
          }
        }
      },

      loading: {
        invoke: {
          src: fetchData,
          onDone: { target: 'Component To Render' }
        },
      },

      error: {},
      success: {},

      'Component To Render': {
        on: {
            target: 'loading',
            actions: ['fetchData', ...other actions],
        },
      },

      OtherComponentToRenderBasedonAction: {
        on: {
            target: 'loading',
            actions: ['fetchData', ...other actions],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    actions: {
      fetchData,
    ...
    },
  },
)

export default myMachine
```

I added what is I am trying for xstate machine, and the above logic caused errors. I need to know if there is something wrong with itand. How can I handle this in a better way?

Comment: The code doesn't look right. The number of [single quotes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/single_quote#Noun) is odd (25). An even number of single quotes would be expected.

Comment: Single (and double) quotes are expected to be balanced (ignoring the content of code comments): A single quote signifies the start of something, and the end of the something is signified by another single quote. They must come in pairs, a count of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 132, 134, 136, 138, 140, 142, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, etc.

Comment: I fixed it, Do you have an idea on implementing xstate in react ?

Comment: Check out the packages react page of the docs: https://stately.ai/docs/xstate-react

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
import { Machine } from 'xstate';

const appMachine = Machine({
  id: 'app',
  initial: 'loading',
  states: {
    loading: {
      on: {
        SUCCESS: 'success',
        ERROR: 'error',
      },
    },
    success: {},
    error: {},
  },
});

enter code here
```